# c# WPF form based search

Tags: c#, wpf, search

i'm looking for a simple solution for a form based search in c# wpf.

My class looks like

```
public class Member
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string MNR { get; set; }
    public int htblAnrede_id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Vorname { get; set; }
    public string Grad { get; set; }
    public Nullable<System.DateTime> GebDat { get; set; }
    public Nullable<System.DateTime> EinOed { get; set; }

    public virtual htblAnrede htblAnrede { get; set; }
    public virtual htblAusGrund htblAusGrund { get; set; }

    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
    public virtual ICollection<tblBasisKennzeichen> tblBasisKennzeichen { get; set; }
    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
    public virtual ICollection<tblBasisKontakte> tblBasisKontakte { get; set; }
}
```

It's binded to a wpf usercontrol.

In my case I open a form and write some stuff into some fields. After that I would have to check from the DataContext every property, every property of the sub objects and every property of every object in the lists to select matches in a list.

Is there a solution or third party tool which I can use to simplify that or do I have to check everything by my self?

Comment: Maybe annotation would be of help [MSDN Docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations(v=vs.110).aspx). This would enforce validation of objects at the model level and it would, possibly, save you to write all of those validations in UI.

Answer (score 0):

Why not add an Equals method in the Member class and just call it where you need:

```
public bool Equals(Member other)
{
    if(other.id != this.id)
        return false;

    if(!other.htblAnrede.Equals(this.htblAnrede))
        return false;

    // fill in the other checks here

    return true;
}
```

You would have to do this for every model that is being compared e.g. htblAnrede, tblBasisKennzeichen, etc.